# PostGIS - Distinguish between geometry updates and value updates

Tags: postgis

I want to create a function that puts the current date in column 1 if any of the columns values are updated (except the geometry) and puts the current date in column 2 if the geometry is updated.

Can we distinguish between geometry updates and updated values?

Comment: By "updated" do you mean strictly updated *and changed*, or do you want this triggered when the value or geometry is updated *with the same value* by a query?

Comment: The simple answer is "of course", but since UPDATE TRIGGER function writing is a pure database task, researching this is really a [dba.se] topic.

Comment: @Vince I think there's a PostGIS-specific dependency that keeps it on-topic here because you need to query into the`geometry_columns` table to find the name of the geometry column to see if that is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do that using 2 functions and 2 triggers. My solution is to create a function and a trigger for the geom column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_your_table_geom_column_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.your_table
    SET column_date_for_geom_column = now() -- OR USE ANOTHER TIMESTAMP/DATE FUNCTION
    WHERE public.your_table.id_column = new.id_column;
    RETURN null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_your_table_geom_column_update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OF geom_column ON public.your_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_your_table_geom_column_update();
```

Then you could do the same for the attribute columns. The change would be just in the `Trigger` part. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_your_table_att_column_update()
RETURN TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.your_table
    SET column_date_for_att_column = now() -- OR USE ANOTHER TIMESTAMP/DATE FUNCTION
    WHERE public.your_table.id_column = new.id_column;
    RETURN null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_your_table_att_column_update_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OF att1_column, att2_column ON public.your_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_your_table_att_column_update();
```

This does the job.

Comment: Does that depend on a specific name for the geometry column? Spatial tables in postGIS are defined in the `geometry_columns` and the name of the geometry column is in a field there.

Comment: I've done propagation using cascading `OLD.colname <> NEW.colname` comparisons to detect if there's actually a change (sometimes also dealing with NULL using `coalesce()`), but it was always a single function per table, hard-coded to the data rules. Testing for geometry change is a nightmare, and I eventually settled on testing the bounding box corners for change.

Comment: You want this to be a `BEFORE` trigger, and alter the respective `NEW` columns inside the functions dedirectly. Apart from that, the `OF` column trigger is spot on.